# How to access activity Argument within ActivityDesigner?

Tags: arguments, workflow-foundation, activitydesigner

I need to get my custom activity's `InArgument` value at `ActivityDesigner`.

MyActivity:

```
[Designer(typeof(ReadTextDesigner))]
public sealed class ReadText : CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<string> ImageName { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

My designer:

```
public partial class ReadTextDesigner
{
    public ReadTextDesigner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.ModelItem is null here.. WHY is it null?
        //How do I get Activity's ImageName here?
    }
}
```

I also have a button as in the image below and when you click on it, I **CAN SET** my custom Activity's value like this:

[image]

```
private void BtnStart_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ModelItem?.Properties["ImageName"]?.SetValue(new InArgument<string>()
        {
            Expression = "some value"
        });
    }
```

XAML:

```
<sapv:ExpressionTextBox 
    Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.ImageName, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter=In }"
    ExpressionType="s:String"
    HintText="Enter a string"
    OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}"
    Width="110"
    Margin="0,5"
    Grid.Row="0"
    MaxLines="1"
    x:Name="TxtImagePath"/>

<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Get Image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="BtnStart_OnClick" x:Name="BtnStart"/>
```

How do I GET Activity InArgument `ReadTextDesigner` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite weird but I found a workaround. Although this is *A* solution, I'm hoping for a much better one;

Since within the constructor, I cannot get the `ModelItem`, I created a new `Thread` apart from the Main Thread. This new Thread waits 2 milliseconds and then tries to get `ModelItem` and it succeeds somehow.

Here is the new modified `ReadTextDesigner` code *(Note: I only changed `ReadTextDesigner` code nothing else)*

```
public ReadTextDesigner()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => { this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SetImage(this)); });
}

private void SetImage(ReadTextDesigner designer)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2);
    if (designer.ModelItem.GetCurrentValue() is ReadText readText)
    {
        var imageName = readText.ImageName?.Expression?.Convert<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imageName))
        {
            //imageName has a value at this point!
        }
    }
}
```

`ModelItem` is not null anymore and carries the necessary value.
Hope this will help someone or someone post a better solution.

Cheers!